# kinectic getting started & troubleshooting

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am planning to design gesture based virtual trial room using kinect xbox. I am new to kinetic & android application. To get started which software need to be downloaded. I downloaded kinectic SDKv2.0.

which software used to write code here. I downloaded Brekel Kinect Pro Body Trial v1.38 32bit which recognise the gesture.
to get started with gesture which platform is good.

Some people say openCV, OpenNI.I could able to differentiate between them. could someone give some idea over it.

[Open kinects](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

Now go with Kinect Windows SDK. Nothing else needed to get the Kinect started. You can track all the joints and even Kinect device tilt motor. But I don't think that you can do anything with android. To get started you can refer to these video set since it explain starting from the device itself. 
[Kinect getting started](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Getting-started-with-Kinect-development-quickly-with-the-Kinect-for-Windows-Quickstart-Series)